# center icon + text on css hovered image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

good day, i am trying to center my icon and text when i hover an image. my problem is that they dont seem to center themselves. ill show both my html and css. also, i am using bootstrap 4. i tried to center both the icon and text using the "overlay" and "overlay-text" tag but both are suspended at the top. any help would be appreciated.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Code:

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #f08300;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-align-center">
      <h2 class="bold_font">BROWSE OUR CARDS</h2><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">

      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_beauty.jpg">
      <div class="overlay">
        <img src="img/icon-beauty-white.png" class="img-responsive center-block card-icon-sm">
        <div class="spacer overlay-text">BEAUTY</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_health.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_wellness.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve using one of the countless image placeholder services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, Wrap the content of what you want to show on the overlay and add CSS to that and adjust the images and text accordingly.

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #f08300;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-content {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-align-center">
      <h2 class="bold_font">BROWSE OUR CARDS</h2><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">

      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_beauty.jpg">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <img src="img/icon-beauty-white.png" class="img-responsive center-block card-icon-sm">
          <div class="spacer overlay-text">BEAUTY</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_health.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_wellness.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are almost always bad answers.

Comment: @connexo I understand that and was about to add the context. Will do all the changes and post it from here after. Thanks!

Comment: this worked well but they all hover at the same time

Comment: Remove the hover on container and add it to `img-responsive`

Answer (score 0):

Try to using flexboxes for a container and wrap icon and icon-text to div with class e.g. .icon-wrapper:

```
.overlay {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #f08300;
}

.overlay-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the image content together in a `relative` element and remove `absolute` position from the text.

something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tus0kdcq/

update: http://jsfiddle.net/jimmyLi/kruz6eqn

Comment: this worked well fixing the hover at the same time issue but the icon and text didnt center properly

Comment: You will need to add more style to the image and text, according to your needs. The images from my example are random, not yours with your needed sizes. If you give the images a specific size, and f.e. the `imageContent` a max width, the rest should be easier to fix from there.

Answer (score -1):

**pls try this css:**

```
<style>
.overlay{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```